# Can not resolve method 'findViewById' in Fragment when i took EditText with Send fragment in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class send extends Fragment {

    private EditText mEditTextTo;
    private EditText mEditTextSubject;
    private EditText mEditTextMessage;


    public send() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);


        mEditTextTo = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_to);
        mEditTextSubject = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_subject); 
       //Cannot resolve method 'findViewById' in all find view by id 
        mEditTextMessage = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);

        Button buttonSend = findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMail();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMail() {
        String recipientList = mEditTextTo.getText().toString();
        String[] recipients = recipientList.split(",");

        String subject = mEditTextSubject.getText().toString();
        String message = mEditTextMessage.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an email client"));
    }
}
```

That is not working code any anyone me to write the exact code
This is my XML of the send fragment................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".send">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="To:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_to"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Subject:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_subject"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailSubject" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Message:"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:lines="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="send" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Logcat Error when run the code

When I run the code it shows no errors but code did not run properly, what should I do now, can anyone help me to implement the send email form the navigation drawer.
 Or anyone adds the code of send fragment which is working properly and send mail pop up??????

```
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3404)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
2019-09-24 11:59:42.995 4015-4015/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.rcs.service.service.JibeService has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.ims.network.e@dbb1e75 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.google.android.rcs.service.service.JibeService has leaked IntentReceiver com.google.android.ims.network.e@dbb1e75 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1333)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1114)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1405)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1378)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1366)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:603)
        at com.google.android.ims.network.a.<init>(SourceFile:48)
        at com.google.android.ims.f.a.a(SourceFile:12)
        at com.google.android.rcs.service.e.a(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.rcs.service.service.JibeService.d(SourceFile:145)
        at com.google.android.rcs.service.service.JibeService.onCreate(SourceFile:91)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3404)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
2019-09-24 11:59:53.518 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:00:00.022 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:00:00.053 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:00:00.146 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:00:06.901 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:00:06.947 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:00:19.692 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:00:32.128 23707-23724/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2019-09-24 12:00:46.157 28486-30420/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2019-09-24 12:00:51.184 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 177 ms
2019-09-24 12:00:51.355 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 170 ms
2019-09-24 12:00:53.341 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 140 ms
2019-09-24 12:00:53.872 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 162 ms
2019-09-24 12:00:54.011 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 140 ms
2019-09-24 12:00:55.543 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 218 ms
2019-09-24 12:01:02.933 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 139 ms
2019-09-24 12:01:03.523 1405-1831/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-09-24 12:01:03.742 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 171 ms
2019-09-24 12:01:03.993 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 164 ms
2019-09-24 12:01:04.029 4851-4872/com.techneo360.pubguide11 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2019-09-24 12:01:04.029 4851-4872/com.techneo360.pubguide11 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf
2019-09-24 12:01:04.029 4851-4872/com.techneo360.pubguide11 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
2019-09-24 12:01:04.030 4851-4872/com.techneo360.pubguide11 E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824
2019-09-24 12:01:04.188 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 195 ms
2019-09-24 12:01:05.998 23707-23724/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2019-09-24 12:01:13.280 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:01:33.353 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:01:33.386 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:01:48.554 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:01:48.586 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:01:48.600 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:01:57.722 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 249 ms
2019-09-24 12:01:57.877 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 153 ms
2019-09-24 12:01:58.013 1396-1396/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 136 ms
2019-09-24 12:02:07.079 4851-4851/com.techneo360.pubguide11 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-09-24 12:02:07.079 4851-4851/com.techneo360.pubguide11 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-09-24 12:02:13.534 23707-23724/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2019-09-24 12:02:25.228 4851-4851/com.techneo360.pubguide11 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-09-24 12:02:27.330 4851-4851/com.techneo360.pubguide11 E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2019-09-24 12:03:00.019 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:03:19.765 23707-23724/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2019-09-24 12:03:42.740 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:05:24.921 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:05:43.286 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:08:00.005 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:08:53.884 23707-23724/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2019-09-24 12:10:00.009 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:11:05.799 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-24 12:11:05.810 23707-23720/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

Comment: You're returning from `onCreateView(..)` on the very first line. The code below that `return` will not execute. Also, the issues with `findViewById` is that you need to find the id on some root view first. So, do `view.findViewById`

Answer (score 3):

You can not directly call findViewById in fragment. For this you have to implement onViewCreated method, this will return view and u can use this view to call findViewById method.

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);
        return view;
    }

     @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mEditTextTo = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_to);
        mEditTextSubject = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_subject); 
        mEditTextMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);
        Button buttonSend = view.findViewById(R.id.button_send);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Init

```
mEditTextTo = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_to);
        mEditTextSubject = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_subject);
```

inside onViewCreated().

In onCreateView  after return statement,  it is not allowed as per return

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have written findViewById after `return` statement, so it will never be executed.

Your fragment should be like this

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Send extends Fragment {

    private EditText mEditTextTo;
    private EditText mEditTextSubject;
    private EditText mEditTextMessage;


    public Send() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_send, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public View onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mEditTextTo = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_to);
        mEditTextSubject = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_subject); 
        mEditTextMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);

        Button buttonSend = view.findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMail();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendMail() {
        String recipientList = mEditTextTo.getText().toString();
        String[] recipients = recipientList.split(",");

        String subject = mEditTextSubject.getText().toString();
        String message = mEditTextMessage.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an email client"));
    }
}
```

Comment: view shows errors

Comment: @JamesLogan Can you add your `fragment_send.xml` and the error logs?

Comment: I added everything

Comment: @JamesLogan avoid asking multiple questions at the same time, it seems you have changed the actually question, previously it was regarding layout and now its about NavDrawer. to ask a good question you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)